# Find lengthiest word in a column containing multiple words in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, stringr

I am working with airports dataset from nycflights13 package. I want to find the word with longest length from the second column i.e. name

I tried 2 ways

1. using strsplit + boundary frunction from stringr on airports$name but somehow now able to get this done effectively.
2. use word function but it only takes first word from the name

   ```
    library(tidyverse)
    library(nycflights13)
    airport <- nycflights13::airports

    strsplit(word(airport$name),boundary("word"))
   ```

Comment: `airport$name[which.max(nchar(airport$name))]`

Comment: My understanding of the question is that the author wants to find "the word with the longest length", not the airport name that is the longest. This intent is further shown by their use of `strsplit`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an approach with `purrr::map`. First, split the `name` column by space. Then apply a custom function to the list that is created. We can use `[` to subset the vector in each list element to be the longest word. We can determine the longest word by applying `nchar` to each element. `which.max` can tell us which one is longest.

The `_char` version of `map` will return a character vector.

```
library(tidyverse)
airport %>%
   mutate(longest = map_chr(strsplit(name," "),
                            ~ .x[which.max(nchar(.x))]),
          wordlength = nchar(longest)) %>%
   select(name,longest,wordlength)
## A tibble: 1,458 x 3
#   name                           longest      wordlength
#   <chr>                          <chr>             <int>
# 1 Lansdowne Airport              Lansdowne             9
# 2 Moton Field Municipal Airport  Municipal             9
# 3 Schaumburg Regional            Schaumburg           10
# 4 Randall Airport                Randall               7
# 5 Jekyll Island Airport          Airport               7
# 6 Elizabethton Municipal Airport Elizabethton         12
# 7 Williams County Airport        Williams              8
# 8 Finger Lakes Regional Airport  Regional              8
# 9 Shoestring Aviation Airfield   Shoestring           10
#10 Jefferson County Intl          Jefferson             9
## … with 1,448 more rows
```

Comment: why use `map`  yet `nchar` is vectorized??

Comment: Thanks, this really helps. I need one step more though to find the length of the longest word in the 'longest' column. I think I can do len(max) but just wondering if a sophisticated way in %>%

Comment: @VaibhavSingh See if my edit clears up your question.

Comment: done, Brilliant. I m still breaking down map & custom function but looks absolutely right

Answer (score 0):

@ian-campbell brilliant answer is great, while browsing I came up with another simpler option to get the same results (incase anyone comes across this question later)

```
library(tidyverse)
library(nycflights13)
airport <- nycflights13::airports

airports %>%
separate_rows(name, sep = ' ') %>% 
mutate(len=nchar(name)) %>% 
select(name,len) %>% 
arrange(desc(len))
```

Another possible answer that I came up while learning from Ian's answer (Also, I am on fire, damn!)

```
airport %>%
  mutate(longest = map(strsplit(name," "),~ nchar(.x))) %>% 
  unnest(longest) %>% 
  arrange(desc(longest))
```